# number increment button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, button

I have an existing html form which use array to store multiple row values. So I do not have a specific name for the same field for different row. In the PHP page i match the row according to the index.
In the form below, how do I make the button + and - to increase and decrease the value of the quantity of the specific row?

ROW 1

```
<input type="text" name="product[]" />
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="" onChange="updatePrice()" />
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" onChange="updatePrice()" />
<input type="button"  onclick="inc(this)" value="+"/>
<input type="button"  onclick="dec(this)" value="-"/>`
```

ROW 2

```
<input type="text" name="product[]" />
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="" onChange="updatePrice()" />
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" onChange="updatePrice()" />
<input type="button"  onclick="inc(this)" value="+"/>
<input type="button"  onclick="dec(this)" value="-"/>
```

ROW 3

```
<input type="text" name="product[]" />
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="" onChange="updatePrice()" />
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" onChange="updatePrice()" />
<input type="button"  onclick="inc(this)" value="+"/>
<input type="button"  onclick="dec(this)" value="-"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you first should to numerate items:

```
<input type="text" name="product[]" />
<input id="price-1" type="text" name="price[]" value="" onChange="updatePrice(1)" /> <!-- row number -->
<input id="qty-1" type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" onChange="updatePrice(1)" />
<input type="button"  onclick="inc('qty-1')" value="+"/>
<input type="button"  onclick="dec('qty-1')" value="-"/>
```

Then use javascript to manipulate items:

```
<script>
function inc(id) {
  stepQty(id, +1);
}
function dec(id) {
  stepQty(id, -1);
}
function stepQty(id, step) {
  var value = $('#'+id).val();
  $('#'+id).val(value + step);
}
function updatePrice(id) {
  var a = $('#price-'+id).val() || 0;
  var b = $('#qty-'+id).val() || 0;
  $('#'+id).val(a*b);
}
</script>
```